# Difference between match and unwrap_or when determining types

Tags: generics, rust, option-type, rust-result

The following is a valid file I can compile with Rust 1.23.0:

```
fn main() {
    let r = String::from("a");
    let a = Some(&r);
    let b = match a {
        Some(name) => name,
        None => "",
    };
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

Whilst the following code

```
fn main() {
    let r = String::from("a");
    let a = Some(&r);
    let b = a.unwrap_or("");
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

Fails with the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:25
  |
4 |     let b = a.unwrap_or("");
  |                         ^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found str
  |
  = note: expected type `&std::string::String`
             found type `&'static str`
```

As far as I can see, the compilers reasoning when determining types here is as follows:

1. In the case with the `match` it determines `b` is a `&str`, since `None => ""` is a `&str` and `Some(name) => name` is a `&String` so it can become a `&str`.
2. In the case where the argument to `unwrap_or` is a  `&str`, instead of typing `b` as a `&str`, it sees there's a difference between the type held in `a` (namely `&String`) and the type of the parameter to `unwrap_or`.

What is the difference between these two cases that makes type deduction work this way?

Is `unwrap_or` implemented to accept the exact same type as the one wrapped by the option instead of just accepting a generic value it place inside a match ?

Furthermore, is there any way to make the `unwrap_or` work in this case, without having to declare a `String` in the external scope  or change the type wrapped by the option ?

One answer I got somewhere else for making them work is this:

```
let b = a.map(|s| s.as_ref()).unwrap_or("")
```

Same effect as the `match`, somewhat shorter, more explicit than the `match` about what's happening to the types.

Answer (score 2):

Loosely speaking, you're half correct.

`a` is an `Option<&String>`. An `&String` can be coerced into an `&str`, but an `&str` cannot be coerced into an `&String`. See this code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("This is a String");
    let a_r = &a;
    foo(a_r);
    bar(a_r);

    let b = "This is an &str";
    // Next line will cause a compilation error if uncommented
    // foo(b);
    bar(b);
}

fn foo(s: &String) {
    println!("Foo: {}", s);
}

fn bar(s: &str) {
    println!("Bar: {}", s);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=01ee6fac74938ef9d92a3250f5eac250&version=stable)

If `foo(b);` is uncommented, it'll tell you that it expected `String`, got `str`.

The `match` statement returns an `&str` (converted from an `&String`), but `unwrap_or` expects the same type as the `Option` that you're calling, an `&String`, which an `&str` cannot become without a manual change (`String::from`, `to_string`, `to_owned`, etc)

Now, I'm going to try to give a brief explanation for *why* this is, but take it with a grain of salt because **I am not an expert in this field**.

---

When using a string literal (`"foo"`), the program, on compilation, creates some segment of memory which represents this text in binary form. This is why a string literal is an `&str` and not just a `str`: It isn't raw text, but instead, it's a *reference to text that already exists at startup*. This means that string literals live in a specific portion of memory which *cannot be modified*, because they're wedged up beside some other object - (`"fooquxegg"`) - and attempting to add characters to a string literal would cause you to *overwrite the next object in line*, which is Very Bad.

A `String`, however, is modifiable. Since we can't determine how many characters are in a String, it has to live in the "heap", where objects *can* be shifted around if something attempts to "grow into" something else, and the `String` type basically serves as a pointer to that text in the heap, much like a `Box<T>` points to a `T` in the heap.

For this reason, while an `&String` can become an `&str` (it's pointing to a certain amount of text *somewhere*, in this case, somewhere in the heap rather than the static memory), an `&str` *cannot be guaranteed to become an* `&String`. If you converted an string literal (like our `"foo"`), which lives in a portion of memory that can't be modified, into an `&String` which *could potentially be modified*, and then attempted to append some characters to it (say `"bar"`), it would overwrite something else.

---

With that being said, look at this code:

```
fn main() {
   let s = "this is an &str";
   let b = String::from("this is a String");
   let s_o : Option<&str> = Some(s);

   let s_or_def = s_o.unwrap_or(&b);
   println!("{}", s_or_def);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f1b69e34ab3ac730495f26a82223adf2&version=stable)

This code is effectively the inverse of your `unwrap_or` example: An `Option<&str>` which is being unwrapped with an `&String` as a default. This will compile, because `&String => &str` is a valid conversion, and the compiler will automatically insert the necessary conversion without needing it to be explicit. So no, `unwrap_or` is not implemented to accept *the exact same* object type; any object which can coerce to `T` (In this case, `T` is `&str`) is valid.

In other words, your `unwrap_or` example fails because *an `&str` cannot become an `&String`*, rather than because the `unwrap_or` method is unusually picky. No, there is likely no way to `unwrap_or` without using a `String`. Your best bet is to simply use `to_string` on a string literal, as per:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Hello, world!");
    let o = Some(s);
    let r = o.unwrap_or("Goodbye, world!".to_string());

    println!("{}", r);
}
```

because [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or), while seeming promising, will not simply allow you to input `|s| &s` for a map (reference is dropped at the end of the closure).

Comment: I mean, the explanation is correct,  but I was more wondering "Why" this the difference in implementation between unwrap_or and match (e.g. why can't we have unwrap_or behave like match) ? Also, you'r example works if I want to return a `String` but not if I want a `&String` (lieftime issues), which is what I'd want from something like .get in a map

Comment: Also, I've edited my post to explain how to use .map. Apparently .map(|s| s.as_ref()) is what you need

Comment: I think I did the best I could to explain what the difference in implementation is: In the `match` case, you're converting an `&String` into an `&str`, which is acceptable, while in the `unwrap_or` case, you're trying to convert an `&str` into an `&String`, which isn't. `unwrap_or` requires an `&String` for type-checking purposes.

Comment: If you need an `&String` then the simple answer is pretty much no, you would need to `let default_string = "".to_string()` in the same scope as the `unwrap_or` so that you could create a reference to it. At least, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Again, just to be clear. In your `match` case, `b` is an `&str`, but in your `unwrap_or` case, `b` is an `&String`. And it's that way by necessity of how Rust defines functions, and which types can coerce into other types. That's why they're different.